# How to get different formats of images

Tags: php

I have this to get user images it's hardcoded for jpg but some users uploaded png and some did gif, how do I make it work for all formats?

```html
 function get_avatar($image, $user_id, $account) 
 {
   $imgurl =$_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"] . "://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . "/files/pictures/picture-" . ($user_id) . ".jpg";

   if (!is_imgurl_good($imgurl)) {
     $imgurl =$_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"] . "://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . "/sites/all/themes/simple_custom/user.png";
   }
   return $imgurl;
 }

function is_imgurl_good($imgurl) {
if (@getimagesize($imgurl))
  return true;//Check that if this returns false the previous function works
  //return false; //Comment out the first line and uncomment this one to show the reverse case.
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can restrict

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

**you should give image type like this**

```
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
```

[see working example here for your better understand](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Comment: That's not I want, in this line    $imgurl =$_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"] . "://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . "/files/pictures/picture-" . ($user_id) . ".jpg";
 I want to add png and gif but don't know how

Comment: if you want allow in this way, it is not possible because "/files/pictures/picture-" . ($user_id) . ".jpg" you directly called extension( ".jpg") in server side,server will not understand,it is valid image or not so if you want all types of image formats,you have to pass like this way  'file_path/file_name(userid).ext (jpg,gif,png).

Comment: Ok that's what I mean but it's not working, I tried this but no luck either:

   $imgurl =$_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"] . "://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . "/files/pictures/picture-" . ($user_id) . ".ext (jpg,gif,png)";

Comment: I tried this    `$imgurl =$_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"] . "://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . "/files/pictures/picture-" . ($user_id) . ".ext (jpg,gif,png)";` but it just shows default picture instead of user pic

Comment: If $user_id value like(1) ,it does not work instead of doing this change or add new column and then put data type as string in your table like $user_id_image then u store like(1.jpg) then retrieve your data.

Comment: Here $user_id_image should have image_name with extension like vi.jpg or 8.jpg

Comment: In table "users" I have column "picture" and there's path with extension 'files/pictures/picture-3.jpg' Don't know how to put it in the code though.

Answer (score 0):

you just do like this example

```
$sql = "SELECT picture FROM table_name where id=1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
    // output data of each row
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
   $user_picture=$row["picture"];


 $imgurl =$_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"] . "://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . "/files/pictures/".$user_picture."";
```